# Getting loop to interate through the mID associated with listID

Tags: php, mysql, loops, concatenation

----- **UPDATED SQL**

```
SELECT listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt,GROUP_CONCAT(mBCFName, mBCLName, moAmt) AS mOfferInfo
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Listing L on (U.uID = L.uID)
INNER JOIN MerchantOffer MO ON (L.listID = MO.listID)
INNER JOIN Merchant M on (M.mID = MO.mId) 
GROUP BY listTitle
ORDER BY listDt DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

**Php**

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    require_once('inc/php/timeAgo.php');
    echo $then;
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 
    echo "<div class='listing'>";
        print '<br>Title: ' . $row['listTitle'] . '<br>Comment: ' . $row['listCmt'] . 
        '<br><br>' . $days . ' days ' . $hours . ' hours ago' . '<br><br>' . '<br>Offer By: ' . $row['mBCFName']. ' ' . $row['mBCLName'] . '<br> for: ' . $row['moAmt'];
    echo "</div>";
    }
    unset($sth1);   
    ?>
```

Gives output like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgdhC.png  (ADMIN PLEASE SHOW)

**It outputs fine now, but I need to format it a bit. How do I add a *space* between mBCFName and mBCLName and *space* after that. (see image above)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing:

```
GROUP BY listTitle
```

I think this will return all the rows you want to see, but the PHP code won't produce the output you expect.

Comment: Help with the php code then? By just removing `GROUP BY listTitle` it doesnt output right, it loops through every field listed.

Comment: But, did you get the wanted offers by listing?

Comment: Not by removing that code, however, i updated the code above and just need to fix the formatting. Can you help? (See updated above please)

Answer (score 0):

Have you dumped out the array $result to view what is actually returned? I always test them with:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($result,true).'<pre>';
```

I would add this as a comment by I can't yet. Sorry for posting it as an 'answer'. It should show you something like:

```
array
(
 ['key1'] => 'value1'
 ['key2'] => 'value2'
 ['key3'] => 'value3'
 ['key4'] => 'value4'
)
```